# Laravel Echo Server in RunCloud Server Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-echo

i'm trying to using Laravel-Echo-Server in my project, in Local there is no error but when i host it to RunCloud the Laravel Echo Server is running but my website cant connect to Laravel Echo Server.. I try to add new custom nginx rule in location.main like laravel echo server doc said but still error

laravel-echo-server.json

```
 {
        "authHost": "https://exampledomain.com",
        "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
        "clients": [],
        "database": "redis",
        "databaseConfig": {
            "redis": {},
            "sqlite": {
                "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
            }
        },
        "devMode": false,
        "host": null,
        "port": "6001",
        "protocol": "https",
        "socketio": {},
        "secureOptions": 67108864,
        "sslCertPath": "path/server.crt",
        "sslKeyPath": "path/server.key",
        "sslCertChainPath": "",
        "sslPassphrase": "",
        "subscribers": {
            "http": true,
            "redis": true
        },
        "apiOriginAllow": {
            "allowCors": true,
            "allowOrigin": "*",
            "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
            "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
        }
    }
```

laravel-echo-setup.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ":" + window.laravel_echo_port
});
```

dashboard.blade.php (in ENV i have set LARAVEL_ECHO_PORT=6001)

```
<script src="//{{ Request::getHost() }}:{{env('LARAVEL_ECHO_PORT')}}/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ url('/js/laravel-echo-setup.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var i = 0;
            window.Echo.channel('vehicle-channel')
                .listen('.App\\Events\\NewVehicle', function (newVehicle){
                    i++;
                    console.log(newVehicle.newVehicle);
                });
        </script>
```

RunCloud Custom Nginx for my webapplication

webapp.location.main.laravelecho.conf

```
#the following would go within the server{} block of your web server config
location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:6001; #could be localhost if Echo and NginX are on the same box
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
```

Here some Picture Laravel Echo Server is Running and My Webapps cant connect to socketio.js

[Laravel Echo Server is Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky8IU.png)

[Failed to Load Socketio.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVayi.png)

Comment: Please read my solution. It will help you on server.

Answer (score 0):

So here I think you need to create a separate file for running laravel-echo-server continuously with help of PM2.

For that, you need to create a file with `anyname.config.js` and add this code inside this file

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'laravel-echo-server',
            script: 'laravel-echo-server',
            instances: 1,  // default 'laravel-echo-server' required 1 instance only to work
            exec_mode: 'fork',  // default
            interpreter: 'node', // default
            args: 'start',
            error_file: './storage/logs/pm2/pm2.error.log',
            out_file: './storage/logs/pm2/pm2.out.log',
            pid_file: './storage/logs/pm2/pm2.pid.log',
            cwd: "PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY_PATH",  // var/www/html/project
        }
    ]
};
```

After that you need to set following code in `laravel-echo-server.json` file on root level of project directory.

```
{
    "authHost": "http://example.com",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

That's it. Now you can start your node laravel-echo-server by watch anyname.config.js file with PM2.

To start PM2 Watch list and run the server use `sudo pm2 start anyname.config.js --watch`